# bootstrap, I cannot get the container to be fluid (full width) col-md-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the coding set to container-fluid so that my col-md-12 column will span the entire screen, but it only spans on the right side and theirs a huge gap on the left. heres my code please help. i do not know if their may be something else that im not seeing that is over riding the container fluid.

```css
<style type="text/css"> .main-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 96.66666666666666%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.btn-min-block {
  min-width: 120px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.btn-clear {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.btn-clear:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.carousel-caption {
  text-align: center;
}
.container1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 9%;
}
.container1img1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
}
.container1img2 {
  margin-left: -24%;
  margin-top: -10%;
}
.container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.demo-content img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.set4 > .row > .col-md-12 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 250px;
}
.set4 h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/mainimg01.png" alt="First slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3></h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/mainimg01.png" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>
                                </h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/mainimg01.png" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>
                               </h3>
                <p>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                        </span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-text hidden-xs">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>
                        <img src="images/dslogo.png" alt="depot square"></h1>
            <h3>
                        Your elegant and affordable destination<br>for family, business and community events.
                    </h3>
            <div class="button">
              <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">MORE ABOUT US</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CHECK AVAILABILITY</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="push">
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="headline">
          <H3>What Makes</H3>
          <h2>Depot Square Special?</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
            Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="container1img1">
            <img src="images/piano1.png">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="container1img2">
              <img src="images/venue1.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container set2">
          <!--Row with three equal columns-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content">
                <img src="images/squareicon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
                <img src="images/pointericon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Central Location</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content">
                <img src="images/foodicon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Catering to Taste</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container set3">
          <!--Row with three equal columns-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content">
                <img src="images/stafficon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Helpful Staff</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
                <img src="images/soundicon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Flexible Service</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="demo-content">
                <img src="images/supporticon.png" class="pull-left">
                <h3>Great Support</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid set4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <h2>Past Events</h2>
              <div class="button1">
                <a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">ALL EVENTS</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">CORPORATE</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block"
                href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">WEDDING</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">COMMUNITY</a><a class="btn btn-clear btn-sm btn-min-block" href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">+</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i didnt know it was attached to container1, what do i need to do to seperate the two sections?

Comment: got it fixed by closing that specific container , thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the container class shouldn't be added to a parent div that is going to be full width unless you want to manually reset the margin/padding for each situation.

[Here's what i think you want](https://jsfiddle.net/TechNinja/qL21usnq/)

[Minimal working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/TechNinja/qL21usnq/1/)

basically, the hierarchy of divs goes `div.container > div.row > div.col-xs-12/ div.col-md-6` (etc..) ..

if you want a full width container eg: `div.conainer-fluid > div.container > div.row > div.col-md-6` (etc..).

Answer (score 0):

This class seems to be the culprit:

```
.container1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 9%;
}
```

Comment/remove those margins and the gutter you are referring to should go away.

EDIT:  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv337vL2/)

Comment: that allowed the container to become full width but the rest of the content changed, is there a way to center the bootstrap to keep the content in the middle

Comment: I usually try to use container instead of container-fluid because it provides 15px margin spacing on both sides.  Is this what you mean?